# Why I cannot connect to SVN from eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, pentaho

I would like to connect svn://source.pentaho.org/svnroot unluckily, I cannot connect to it from eclipse (I installed subclipse)

http://db.tt/xeYI8rqj

but I can browser it from browser (eg chrome)

http://db.tt/pd4Qf5xx

Do you know the reason of that??

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **correct** protocol

- Browser access `http://` repository
- In Eclipse you tried `svn://`

Server may not support both protocols at the same time

But, because I can reach both types of repos, I suppose svn-port is blocking somehow on the road (corporate policy on border-firewall?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!!  May I know your SVN software(Your screen capture above)  can download the source code to local disk for modification?   If yes  where can I download it. Thank you very much!!

Comment: @TimmyLo - it's just [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) repo-browser, and yes, TSVN can checkout|commit (and perform any other svn-related tasks)